# How to access property into XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am a newbie in WPF
As mention I have property in class

```
public ObservableCollection<Company> GetCompany
        {
            get
            {
                return _collectionCompany;
            }
        }
```

How can I access it in XAML?
I am trying like this:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Company" ItemsSource="{StaticResource GetCompany}"  Width="200"></DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

But it gives an error.

Answer (score 2):

first you need to allow the xaml to access the property by setting it's DataContext:

if the property is in the codebehind, add this to the window element:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"
```

else if it's in a separate viewModel class (the preferred method)

```
public MainWindow()
{
    MainWindowViewModel viewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
    this.DataContext = viewModel;

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

this viewmodel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged if you wan't the UI to be updated when the property changes (I assume so), however if the UI is to only have write access to the property this isn't necessary.

```
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{       
    ObservableCollection<Company> _company;
    public ObservableCollection<Company> Company
    {
        get
        {
            return _company;
        }
        set
        {
            if ( _company != value )
            {
                _company = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged( "Company" );
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged( string name )
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if ( handler != null ) handler( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( name ) );
    }
```

Just on a side note, try to avoid GetCompany & SetCompany as property names, instead use this.Company to differentiate it from the class name.

Answer (score 1):

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Company" ItemsSource="{Binding GetCompany}"  ...
```

However you must look that this property is accessible through the markup. If the property is defined in your code-behind, you can write in the constructor:

```
DataContext=this;
```

Comment: I have tried with above code but still combobox is not filled up